# A thermodynamics problem from a Cambridge university entrance test

Tags: thermodynamics

A closed container of volume V is filled by water at temperature T. Imagine that the interaction between the molecules suddenly disappeared. What would be the pressure?

Could someone please show their method, having in mind that it is for year 13 students (17/18 years old) who haven't learnt at university level.

Comment: Do you know what an ideal gas is?

Comment: This site is unfortunately not for homework. Instead of asking to have it solved, ask for a specific physics issue that prevents you from solving it.

Comment: @Steeven It is not homework. It is a question about what good highschool students may be expected to know.

Comment: yes, and i have come across the equations,pV = NkT and
pV = nRT and E = 3/2kT

Comment: But this does not need an equation.

Comment: Damn, could you elaborate please?

Comment: I would have answered that the pressure will be of the order of 10$^3$ atmosphere. Probably some reasoning is expected, not just a number?

Comment: I understand that; that doesn't change the fact that the questions asks the problem solved. Rather ask about a physics issue.

Comment: Okay. Yeah they will ask you about the answer you got afterwards at interview. I used the equations to get 831VT/2400 (or RVT/24) by using the fact 1 mol occupies 24 dm^3. Then working out the mean square speed then factoring in to PV = 1/3Nmc^2 etc.

Comment: Ah, so you are asking here for help before the interview? Then I agree with @Steeven

Comment: Hmm @Pieter this is not about agreeing. Homework-**like** questions are in risk of being closed - there is a page with the site-policy on that somewhere. To avoid this being closed, I'm requesting a proper physics question.

Comment: To **I.Wood**: use the ideal gas equation (you have mentioned it alread) and then use another equation to find $n$ first; that other equation could include Avogadro's number. Then you should be able to find the pressure with those two and one more of the equations you mentioned.

Comment: In lots of ways this is a homework type question but what you have to realise is that the answer is not the only thing which is being asked for in the interview.  In the main what the interviewer is looking at it are the Physics concepts which are being used to get the answer.  I have given a hint of what might happen in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to realise is that as soon as the interactions disappear it becomes an ideal gas problem and so can be answered in a number of ways.

One way is to use the ideal gas equation, $PV=nRT$.

To find the pressure $P$ one needs to estimate the number of moles, $n$, of water with density $1000\; \rm kg\; m^{-3}$ in a volume, $V$ and the temperature of the water.  So knowing the molar gas constant $R$ the pressure can be found.

If you do it this way you will find it to be a pressure a number of orders of magnitude larger than atmospheric pressure.
So you might be asked if you consider this to be a reasonable value for the pressure.
The questioning might then lead onto a consideration of a result from the kinetic theory of gases $P=\frac 13 \rho \bar {c^2}$ and a simpler way of obtaining an estimate of the pressure using an estimate for atmospheric pressure and the density of air.